# how to convert a JPEG to an image matrix in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, jpeg

I need to convert a JPEG image to a matrix. I want to run SVD on the matrix.

I had used

```
library(jpeg)
library(biOps)
myjpg <- readJpeg("Snapshot_1.jpg")
> dim(myjpg)
[1] 398 506   3
```

I want to get an image matrix of "myjpg" in grey scale preferably. Is there an R command which does that.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
imagedata(myjpg, type="grey")
```

Comment: Thanku... this is exactly what i wanted. :)

Comment: Now that biOps is no longer available, any other way of converting an JPEG image to an matrix in R?

Comment: @SaqibAli The code for the imagedata function is still available.  You can find it on github among other places and use the code as desired.