# Image Vectorizer

Tags: image-processing, vectorization, object-recognition

I'm looking for a library/tool/image processing technique which can create vectors out of images (similar to text vectorization like TFIDF or so). Can anybody share some ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Please specify your programming language. There are languages like Python , R has lot of library for this. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what programming language you are using. Below is a sample i am using in **R**

This is how to use the **Pixmap** library to read in an image as a matrix.

> library(pixmap)
>
> ## the next command may only work on Linux
>
> system("convert foo.tiff foo.ppm")
>   img <- read.pnm("foo.ppm")

To get info on your new object:

> str(img)

Although included in the previous output, the size of the image can be extracted by:

> img@size

Then to extract the red channel from the image for the first ten rows:

> myextract <- img@red[1:10,]

Or to extract the entire red channel to an actual matrix:

> red.mat<-matrix(NA,img@size[1],img@size[2])
>   red.mat<-img@red

Refer this : [how to convert a JPEG to an image matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050974/how-to-convert-a-jpeg-to-an-image-matrix-in-r)

You can use **Python- numpy** also

```
>>> arr = np.array(im)
>>> arr = np.arange(150).reshape(5, 10, 3)
>>> x, y, z = arr.shape
>>> indices = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(x*y), (y, x))).T
#or indices = np.hstack((np.repeat(np.arange(y), x)[:,np.newaxis], np.tile(np.arange(x), y)[:,np.newaxis]))
>>> np.hstack((arr.reshape(x*y, z), indices))
array([[  0,   1,   2,   0,   0],
       [  3,   4,   5,   0,   1],
       [  6,   7,   8,   0,   2],
       [  9,  10,  11,   0,   3],
       [ 12,  13,  14,   0,   4],
       [ 15,  16,  17,   1,   0],
       [ 18,  19,  20,   1,   1],
       [ 21,  22,  23,   1,   2],
       [ 24,  25,  26,   1,   3],
       [ 27,  28,  29,   1,   4],
       [ 30,  31,  32,   2,   0],
       [ 33,  34,  35,   2,   1],
       [ 36,  37,  38,   2,   2],
       ...
       [129, 130, 131,   8,   3],
       [132, 133, 134,   8,   4],
       [135, 136, 137,   9,   0],
       [138, 139, 140,   9,   1],
       [141, 142, 143,   9,   2],
       [144, 145, 146,   9,   3],
       [147, 148, 149,   9,   4]])
```

Where arr = np.array(im) is my image